# How to bind complex data to UI in KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have HTML code as below. I am binding the data to labels.

```
data-bind="text: employeeData.Id, valueUpdate:'keyup'"

data-bind="text: employeeData.Name, valueUpdate:'keyup'"
```

And my knockout script is as below:

```
self.employeeData = { Id: ko.observable(" "),Name:ko.observable(" ") };

self.getEmployee = function(data, event){
    $.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/api/Values/GetEmployee',
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    crossDomain:true,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        self.employeeData = ko.observable(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

I am getting the data from Ajax call properly, but it is not getting bound to the UI. Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: where is your call to ko.applyBindings?

Comment: @BonMacalindong: Its there at the bottom of the file. Other binding are happening fine, like on click of some button I am able to change the label text which is of string type. In the above example I am dealing with complex object and that is where I am having trouble

Comment: Why you do `self.employeeData = ko.observable(data);` ? Doesn't this over-write your model? Shuldn't you do `self.employeeData.Id(data.Id)` ? Did you read the docs? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Comment: @Cristy, self.employeeData.Id(data.Id) this is working fine but what If I have 30+ attributes ? writing all of them individually is hectic right? and what can we do in case of List for that matter(list of employees).

Comment: @yashwanth You can create a function to load the data into your object. If all the attribute names are the same, you can simply iterate through the keys of the `data` object and update the values of your observables as I said above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `employeeData` property is not *observable*, so when the ajax `success` handler runs (probably after `applyBindings` was run) the property will be overwritten with a reference to an observable.

Do something like this instead:

```
function getEmployee(data) {
  data = data || {};
  return {
    Id: ko.observable(data.Id || " "),
    Name: ko.observable(data.Name || " ")
  };
}

self.employeeData = ko.observable(getEmployee());

self.getEmployee = function(data, event){
  $.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/api/Values/GetEmployee',
    success: function (data) {
      // option 1:
      self.employeeData(getEmployee(data));

      // option 2:
      self.employeeData().Id(data.Id);
      self.employeeData().Name(data.Name);

      // option 3:
      // use ko.mapping library and its update functionality

      // option 4:
      // use constructor functions and give them a "loadData" method, for ex.
    }
  }
});
```

I recommend looking into "constructor functions" for view models, as well as the ko.mapping plugin.

Comment: Isn't this inefficient to re-build the entire object instead of using the knockouts update functions? (`model.attributeName(newValue)`, eg: `employeeData.Id(27)` ?

Comment: Aye, a very good point, but I had assumed those two properties might be just the ones in OP's example. I'll update the answer a bit to account for both ways.